# Running scrapy spider on multiple machines (parallel scraping)

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been using Scrapy for quite a while now and I have been searching if it is possible to use one spider or multiple spiders on different machines (same IP) at the same time (parallel scraping) to speed Scrapy up; but I haven't found anything related to this. Does anyone know about it?

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way of doing this but you could accomplish a distributed crawl by using multiple scrapyd instances. You would just have to issue separate schedule requests (1+ to each scrapyd server instance).

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls